# How do I grab the CSV from a Data Explorer URL?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm building an app that works by users punching in big lists of questions. And I want them to be able to use the Data Explorer to create these lists.

My preferred way of getting the data would be a user copying a link to a Query. I've tried grabbing the csv programatically using this kind of URL:

```
http://data.stackexchange.com/ubuntu/csv/102689
```

But I'm getting an error page ("Server Error in '/' Application."). Presumably, the data explorer doesn't like it when you grab the results programmatically.

I don't want to cheat. What is the most straightforward way to have a user creater a query, and fetch the results of the query in my app? (If at all possible, the user shouldn't have to upload the file, or copy and paste the results)

Comment: I'd be interested in this too. I assume there is not an API interface for the Data Explorer?

Comment: I've discovered [from this answer](http://stackapps.com/a/6562/34700) that SEDE does not presently have an API interface.

Comment: @halfer, [SEDE allegedly has implemented OData endpoints](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43991/implement-odata-api-for-stack-overflow) but this seems mostly kaput and I've no bloody clue how to use it.

Comment: Thanks @Brock - sadly it looks like [it's been disabled now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254209/184183), as of April 2015.

Comment: This has been asked on [Meta SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250977/184183) as well. Apparently downloading using cURL isn't impossible, as others have said here.