# Can revisions be returned from the API, filtered by user?

Tags: support, api, users, revisions

I see that question or answer revisions can be returned from the API either [by post ID](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-ids) or [by GUID](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/revisions-by-guids).

I'd like to obtain this data filtered by user, e.g. "all revisions made by user X". However, I cannot see there is any way to do so. There are common parameters available (min, max, fromdate, todate, and sort) but `user_id` does not seem to be among them.

I know I can see [suggested edits](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits), but if I understand it correctly, this only applies to users under the immediate-approve threshold, and thus won't capture revisions from higher-rep users.

Is what I want to do possible?

Interestingly, it seems that [screen-scraping is unexpectedly not verboten](https://stackapps.com/q/4814/34700). Perhaps that is an option, in lieu of a specific API feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, no.  The API currently does not have any easy way to track a user's edits.

You can see what returns edit information by scrolling to the bottom of [the  `revision` object, documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/revision).  Currently, it says:

> **Methods That Return This Type**
>       `posts/{ids}/revisions`
>       `revisions/{ids}`

Such cross-references are on every object's doc page, and none of them are of help for getting a user's edits.

**You can get this information from [a SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/358761/get-all-edits-by-a-user?UserId=472495), if you don't mind the data being up to a week old.** (PS: not all maniacs have 13,510 edits and counting! (^_^)  )

Ironically, [you can get a user's *suggested* edits](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/suggested-edits-on-users) <sup>(As you noted)</sup>, but not his actual edits!

---

Edits would be an excellent addition to [the `network_activity` type](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-activity).
**==> Consider making a feature request. <==**

Or, request that a `/users/{ids}/edits` route be added.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts (and yes, I am a keen editor ;-). Can I run a SEDE query via an API call? The data being up to a week old isn't ideal, but not a deal-breaker IMO.

Comment: No.  There is no API for SEDE, but that would be a great thing to have!  You can pester @TimStone, or  Nick Craver, etc.,  to add one or [submit a pull-request](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer) yourself. (hint, hint) :D

Comment: Thanks. I see folks have tried [programmatically downloading the SEDE CSV file](http://stackapps.com/q/2447/34700) without success. So, yes, an API would be great, but sadly I am not a .net dev, so I don't think I'll be able to assist here! I will certainly raise feature requests though.

Comment: PS, I didn't necessarily mean to make a new (almost duplicate) post -- although I think it's okay in this case.  You could have just edited *this* question. ;)

Comment: I can delete that and modify this one, if you'd rather? Since I am a frequent editor of other people's posts I am happy to take advice `:-)`.

Comment: Don't bother.  If Tim doesn't mind, I don't.

Comment: Cool. For future readers, here's my feature requests: [post revisions by user](http://stackapps.com/q/6563/34700) and [a SEDE API](http://stackapps.com/q/6564/34700).