# Please provide a way to get Post Edits, filtered by user

Tags: feature-request, api, api-v2.2, revisions

I recently discovered [from this question](https://stackapps.com/q/6561/34700) that the API does not support filtering revisions by user. I am interested in looking at a user's edit history programmatically (with their permission) and at present the only way to do this is via screen-scraping, which is not ideal.

A helpful answer to the above question suggests that this could be implemented with one of these endpoints in a future release:

- `users/{id}/network-activity` - with a new event type
- `/users/{ids}/edits` - new endpoint

I don't have a preference as to which is implemented, as long as all edits are available (I am aware that some site events are accessible only in a 15-minute window, and that wouldn't be so useful for my use-case).