# Get users based on location?

Tags: support, api, users

I want to get site users by their location but I don't see any method for that.
And it's not possible with a filter either.

Is there any way to get users based on location or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with the API:

1. Neither the API, nor the main sites, provides a way to search on location.
2. You can't even brute-force it, by downloading every user either. Because:

   1. There are [currently 4,972,549 users on Stack Overflow](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users#order=desc&sort=reputation&filter=!%29V%29MSZJUTLp&site=stackoverflow&run=true).
   2. You can download, at most, 1 million user records per day. (10,000 API quota times pagesize of 100.)

   You *could* brute-force smaller sites that have less than 1 million users, but I wouldn't recommend it.

---

You can **search by location using SEDE.** For example:

[Stack Overflow users who claim to reside in Bangladesh](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411455/find-users-by-location?LocationQry=Bangladesh)

Note that SEDE data may be up to 1 week old and [there is no API for it](https://stackapps.com/questions/6564/please-provide-a-way-to-download-sede-data-via-an-api).

Comment: Thanks for answer, i know about SEDE , but i wanted to get the user real time based on any location not a fixed one that's why i was looking for a method in se api but that's not possible right now :(

Comment: Keep in mind that Stack Overflow was explicitly founded NOT to be a social site and the owners and developers consistently stress that we should ignore users AMAP and concentrate on quality Q&A. ... For this reason, it is unlikely that any more user-search capabilities will be added. But, you can try making a feature request on [metase].

Comment: what is meant by AMAP ?

Comment: It's [a common English acronym](https://www.acronymfinder.com/AMAP.html): "As much as possible"